# Sharepoint 2013 search result tabular display template example

Tags: display-template

Are there any tabular search result display templates that all you need to do is plug in the right managed properties and it works! that has a decent layout and maybe toggles rows in color and has borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Elio Struyf's Table layout with sorting and with multi sorting display templates.

Reference links:

[Table layout with sorting](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Sorting%20Templates%20(CSWP))

[Table layout with multi-sorting](https://github.com/SPCSR/DisplayTemplates/tree/master/Search%20Display%20Templates/Table%20Layout%20with%20Multi%20Sort%20Templates%20(CSWP))

Related blog post - [Table layout display template with managed property sorting](https://www.eliostruyf.com/table-layout-display-template-with-managed-property-sorting/)

Basically, just copy paste the display template from the git repo into your site collection's display template folder. You just need to specify your managed properties and it display's data in tabular format. You will need to adjust css for row color and border.

Comment: Thank you!  I will work on this.  If I have any questions along the way Ill ask.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much Gautam,  these templates work great!  Have them uploaded using the .js file as well.  All I have left to do is finish mapping the properties I want displayed.  i will attack that on Monday